# BASIC Output to RS-232 with Tandy Model 100

Tags: basic, trs-80-model-100

I want to use a program like this on a Tandy Model 100:

```
10 REM COM Port SetUp 9600 8N1??? 
20 PRINT "TRS-80 Model-100 is sending this out!"
30 GOTO 20
```

I need to know what line(s) to replace line 10 with?

Comment: I think you may need an expansion interface for the TRS-80. It came with a manual, too. Do you have such hardware included?

Comment: Hi,  The Model 100 computer has a RS-232 port on the back, I just want BASIC to send the output from the program out the RS-232 port.  No expansion ports should be needed.

Comment: Ah. I did have one. But it was a very long time ago. I seem to recall getting an interface for it and it had a separate manual. My mistake, then. What do you have on the other end of the interface?

Comment: @wperko Please add the information what system that is about as part of the question.

Answer (score 15):

The BASIC is a rather straight Microsoft 8 bit variant, so just open COM as a file:

```
10 Open "COM:88N1" FOR OUTPUT AS 1
20 PRINT #1, "TRS-80 Model-100 is sending this out!"
30 GOTO 20
```

Values are:

- **COM:** select the serial port
- **8** selects 9600 Bd
- **8** is word length
- **N** for no parity
- **1** for a single stop bit

See [page 125](https://archive.org/details/trs-80-m-100-user-guide/page/124/mode/2up) of the **[Model 100 Owner's Manual](https://archive.org/details/trs-80-m-100-user-guide/mode/2up)** for a description of all parameters, as well as [page 165](https://archive.org/details/trs-80-m-100-user-guide/page/164/mode/2up) for the open command.

A more in depth description and tutorial examples is provided in the **[Model 100 Basic Language Lab](https://archive.org/details/Model_100_Basic_Language_Lab_1983_Tandy/mode/2up)** by [Lesson #14 Using the COM Option](https://archive.org/details/Model_100_Basic_Language_Lab_1983_Tandy/page/n169/mode/2up) starting at page 165.

Comment: Hi,  My Model 100 required "COM:88N1E" ... now with the "E" it runs ... thanks!